# Getting and using current directory in c# script

Tags: c#

This is just a sample, but it will help illustrate what I'm trying to do.

I know how to get the current directory as shown in the script below, and I can can set a file `variable`.

The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to make it create a folder and put the file in the folder

For example (using the variables below)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cd = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            Directory.CreateDirectory(cd: \5app\);
            File.Copy(c:\xyz.txt, cd: \5app\xyz.txt

        }
    }
}
```

I know what I have written above is not correct because vs10 tells me so, but doesn't give me very much help.

Comment: I would recommend looking at MSDN's documentation for this.  It appears that you have just found this function and started throwing parameters at it.  If you look at the example in the documentation you will have a good starting point for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @abe-meissler This. I included links to the specific MSDN articles for the functions `CreateDirectory` and `Copy` in my answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a parenthesis and a semicolon, and, especially, arguments of methods `Directory.CreateDirectory()` and `File.Copy()` are strings, put them inside quotes:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cd = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            Directory.CreateDirectory(cd + @"\5app\");
            File.Copy(@"c:\xyz.txt", cd + @"\5app\xyz.txt");
        }
    }
}
```

MSDN references: [Directory.CreateDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.100).aspx), [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy(v=vs.100).aspx)

Thanks to **[Cole Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1350209/cole-johnson)** for pointing out that it shouldn't be `@"cd: \5app\"`.

Comment: Cd: doesn't go in quotes. It's a parameter name for explicit parameters

Answer (score 3):

You don't use quotes.

In addition, I recommend against explicit parameter naming. If you look at the CIL generated when using explicit parameters, there is a performance downgrade as the parameter variables are saved to a local variable, then passed. This results in an unneeded `strfld` command.

Comment: also close your `File.Copy(c:\xyz.txt, cd: \5app\xyz.txt` statement

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with your code, which Compiler Errors will likely help you to unravel:

The method `Directory.CreateDirectory(string path)` requires a string, which is encased in "".
Here is an MSDN article on how to use [Directory.CreateDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.createdirectory%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Same with the method `File.Copy(string source, string destination)`
Here is an MSDN article on how to use [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Since Directory.GetDirectory() returns a string, you can just concatinate your specific directory to the result. But remember to use proper [Escape Sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) in your strings for things like *Backslash*.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1 
{ 
    class Program 
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        { 
            string cd = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); 
            Directory.CreateDirectory(cd + "\\5app\\"); 
            File.Copy("c:\\xyz.txt", cd + "\\5app\\xyz.txt");
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: @user1408958 If one of these posts is your answer, please be sure to mark it.